# How to get html in form of text?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

- **Problem**: when I useconsole.log(`${ref.current}`) I got a text like this `[object HTMLTableElement]` despite I need to get a text like `<h1> bla bla bla</h1>`.
- **Goal**: How to get the HTML value in form of a string in Reactjs or in reactjs general.
- **Note**: `ref.current` come from `const ref =React.useRef(null)` it is just like `document.querySelector('.smth')`

Comment: Why do you use `console.log(\`${ref.current}\`)` instead of `console.log(ref.current)`? You can read different properties like `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
console.log(ref.current.innerHTML) // for content

console.log(ref.current.outerHTML) // for tag and content
```